# Mockito mock a context.getApplicationInfo in Android Unit Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

First time writing unit tests ever, so I read the Android developer guide on mockito. I am trying to achieve something similar when they mock the context, however, I am getting a NullPointerException on my test because I'm not correctly substituting `mMockContext.getApplicationInfo()`

Test looks like this:

```
package com.cinnamint.cotidiano;


import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MainUnitTest {

    @Mock
    Context mMockContext;

    @Mock
    ApplicationInfo mApplicationInfo;

    @Test
    public void dateValidator_CorrectNumberOfWordsGrab_ReturnWords() throws Exception {

        when(mMockContext.getApplicationInfo()).thenReturn(mApplicationInfo);

        WordDatabase testWordDatabase = new WordDatabase(mMockContext);

        testWordDatabase.open();
        List<Words> results = testWordDatabase.getEveryWordByDate(4);
        testWordDatabase.close();
        assertThat(results.size(), is(4));

    }
}
```

I should note that the database is using SQLiteAssetHelper, and NOT accessing an external database through online protocol or anything like that. The database is stored as an asset to the APK and is only loaded once.

LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.<init>(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:109)
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.<init>(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:129)
    at com.cinnamint.cotidiano.WordDatabase.<init>(WordDatabase.java:20)
    at com.cinnamint.cotidiano.MainUnitTest.dateValidator_CorrectNumberOfWordsGrab_ReturnWords(MainUnitTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Edit: New version of test

```
@Test
public void dateValidator_CorrectNumberOfWordsGrab_ReturnWords() throws Exception {

    when(mMockContext.getApplicationInfo()).thenReturn(mApplicationInfo);
    when(mMockContext.getAssets()).thenReturn(mAssetManager);
    when(mAssetManager.open("null/databases/word.db")).thenReturn(mInputStream);

    WordDatabase testWordDatabase = new WordDatabase(mMockContext);

    when(testWordDatabase.getWritableDatabase()).thenReturn(mSQLiteDatabase);

    testWordDatabase.open();
    List<Words> results = testWordDatabase.getEveryWordByDate(4);
    testWordDatabase.close();
    assertThat(results.size(), is(4));

}
```

New stacktrace:

```
com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:455)
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400)
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
    at com.cinnamint.cotidiano.MainUnitTest.dateValidator_CorrectNumberOfWordsGrab_ReturnWords(MainUnitTest.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the getApplicationInfo's case you probably should give back an ApplicationInfo mock. lie this:

```
when(mMockContext.getApplicationInfo()).thenReturn(mApplicationInfo);
```

When you try to test a class, you write scenarios and set up the mocks for the given scenario.

Comment: Thank you, I added       `when(mMockContext.getApplicationInfo()).thenReturn(mApplicationInfo);` but it still failed the test with the same logcat. I'll keep trying to play around with mApplication Info.

Comment: There are probably other calls to you mocks, you need to mock them all.

Comment: Yeah I've been adding more mocks whenever I run into a NPE. Since I'm using a third party library `SQLiteAssetHelper`, it seems to be a huge amount of trouble. Is that normal for testing? I've mocked 5 objects and I am stuck on an exception where I need the database path string, which I don't know how to mock. Is there a better way to restructure my test to accomplish what I want? Or is it not recommended to test this?

Comment: Welcome to testing :), the more dependency a class has the more you need to mock, too much mocking can be the sign of too complex class. 5 mock is not that much yet.

Comment: Well that's a relief. I'm still digging into where the test is getting hung up. The SQLiteAssetException appears to be from it not finding `null/databases/word.db'.

Comment: I think I'm going to try using an instrumented unit test instead. I couldn't mock all the way. Thanks anyway